# Why is it essential to uproot a plant just before flowering in order to see nodules?

Tags: botany

In my textbook it was written - Uproot any plant from common pulses **just before flowering** and you will see near spherical outgrowths on the roots .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't necessary to pull them just before flowering. It is merely that the [optimal time to check for effective nodulation is about 10-12 weeks post](https://grdc.com.au/news-and-media/news-and-media-releases/south/2020/august/remember-the-four-cs-when-checking-legume-nodulation) emergence, which also happens to be about the same time as flowering in many species.

Root nodules for the nitrogen fixing legumes develop throughout the life span of the plant. The nodules contain bacteria from the genus *[Rhizobium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhizobium)* which are attracted to the root by release of certain flavenoids. The root hair tip then curls around the bacteria and forms a symbiotic relationship between the plant and the bacteria.

As the nodule formation takes some time to develop and become big enough to see, the nodules are often easily seen about the time the seasonal plants mature as this is also when the nodules get large. However, nodulation [starts within 48 h post-inoculation](https://doi.org/10.1104/pp.105.070326)<sup>1</sup>, so if you took a root tip and looked with sectioning and a microscope you could find nodule initiation at about 48 h.

ref:

1. Dasharath Prasad Lohar, Natalya Sharopova, Gabriella Endre, Silvia Peñuela, Deborah Samac, Christopher Town, Kevin A.T. Silverstein, Kathryn A. VandenBosch, Transcript Analysis of Early Nodulation Events in Medicago truncatula      , Plant Physiology, Volume 140, Issue 1, January 2006, Pages 221–234, https://doi.org/10.1104/pp.105.070326